# While loop doesn't end for values of count > no_of_messages in Python

Tags: python, loops, amazon-sqs

I have this code snippet, which goes through the bounce queue in sqs, prints details about the message, deletes the message. `no_of_messages` is the number of messages in the sqs queue I want to view and delete. The code is as follows:

```
rs = que.get_messages(max_messages_in_que)
count=0
if len(rs)!= 0:
    while count <= no_of_messages:
        for i in range(len(rs)):
            count+=1
            message = json.loads(rs[i].get_body())['Message']
            bounce_message=(json.loads(message))
            print(bounce_message['mail']['timestamp'] + ' - ' + bounce_message['mail']['destination'][0])
            conn.delete_message(que,rs[i])
        time.sleep(1)
        rs = que.get_messages(max_messages_in_que)
```

Obviously, this should end when `count` is greater than `no_of_messages`. But it doesn't. What is wrong?

Comment: Is the length of rs 0?  (That way count would never get incremented, since it's only in the for loop.)

Comment: just before the while, I have another if statement that I've not included for brevity. ```if len(rs)!= 0:```

Comment: don't you need it inside the `while`?  Maybe ... `if not len(rs): break`

Comment: That will only test the first `rs`, not when you repeat.

Comment: normally, if the counter starts from zero, the loop tests for `count < no_of_messages`. When it starts from 1, the loop tests for `count <= no_of_messages`. BTW, why are you using `i` as an index in `rs`? Study python's `for` loops, they can make your life much simpler

Comment: @Barmar good point. will fix that.

Comment: @Pynchia this one? - https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: I am sure there are better resources. Try substituting `for i in range(len(rs)):` with `for el in rs`. `el` is now your `rs[i]` (example `Lists as an iterable` in the link you have provided). Learn about Python's iteration protocol, iterables, iterators, etc.

Comment: aaah...yes. How did I miss that? Older code of mine. Will update that. thanks. @Pynchia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the definition, I'm guessing, but have you defined `no_of_messages` as a string? An integer is always < a string no matter what value it is.

Try

```
while count <= int(no_of_messages):
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

I do this for no_of_messages:

```if (len(sys.argv) <= 1):
        sys.exit("Insufficient arguments.\nUsage: sqs.py <queue_name> <no_of_messages>")
    else:
        que_name = sys.argv[1]
        no_of_messages = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv)>2 else 20```